# Remove this unused method parameter in Sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I got some trouble with a `sonar` issue:

> Remove this unused method parameter "messageId".

well my method looks like:

```
private static Optional<Status> getStatus(Member member, String messageId) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(member)
            .map(Member::getTraffic)
            .map(Traffic::getSymlinks)
            .map(messages -> messages
                    .stream()
                    .filter(message -> message.getMessageId().equals(messageId))
                    .findFirst()).flatMap(message -> message.map(Message::getStatus));
}
```

the `messageId` is used inside the `equals` of the filter.
It is no field. It is the method parameter.

Is that a `sonar` bug or have I overlooked something?
We are using Sonar 5.6

Comment: Huh. It looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, looks like a Bug . Seems this got recently addressed in SonarJava 5.0 (compatible with SonarQube 6.7+) which got released last December

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2115

Comment: hell yes. our version is a little bit older than that. thx a lot

Comment: was referring to SonarJava's version https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava. This requires SonarQube 6.7+